# LWC input field tag, add custom values in standard picklist

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

In lightning-input-field, I am displaying Opportunity Stage field. My record type has 10 picklist values. I want to display only 5 picklist values. Is there a way we can set picklist options in the lightning-input-field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
The `lightning-input-field` component is supposed to get it's information from the metadata of your org.

What you're after is custom logic that sits outside standard Salesforce, so you either need to update the record type to only have those 5 values, or you'll need to create your own LWC that has this custom logic

Comment: Thank You......